# Can't understand the result of InnerClass

Tags: python

I has met a problem when I was learning InnerClass of Python

```
class Innerclass:
    "the example of innerclass"
    string='hello world'

    class inner_class:
        msg='inner class'
        print(msg)

    def func0(self):
        print(self.string)
        print("public method")
        self._func1()  #the use of private method

    def _func1(self):   #private method can't be used directly
        print(self.string)
        print("private method")

    @classmethod
    def classfun2(self):
        print(self.string)
        print("class method")

    @staticmethod
    def staticfun3():
        print(Innerclass.string)
        print("static method")


g=Innerclass()
#public method and private method g.func0()
#class method g.classfun2()
#static method
g.staticfun3()
```

The results of this:

```
inner class
hello world
public method
hello world
private method
hello world
class method
hello world
static method
```

what i was confused is that why did 'inner class' print first not at last

Comment: Please fix you code indentation.

Comment: Because this is global entry point for the class object. Every time you instantiate the class (i.e create an object) it will print "inner class" first.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, inner classes are *very* rarely useful in Python. There's no special advantage to defining a class inside another one, and there's not usually much reason for doing so.

That said, your question is not particularly specific to inner classes: the same would happen with a standalone class. Class definitions are themselves executable statements, and anything at class level is executed when the class definition is read. So any print statement will be executed immediately it is read.

Note that you never instantiate inner_class, so it's not clear why you expected it to print last, in any case.